How do I get rid of this error when attempting to install the bpy Python package on JetBrains PyCharm?
I am using a Mac with Apple Silicon running macOS Sequoia.
When attempting to install the bpy Python package (used to run Blender scripts) on JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition, it returns an error. When clicking "details," it states:
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 2.82.1 Requires-Python >=3.7, <3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bpy

It also suggests running the following commands, and states that if they crash, the problem is not with the IDE.
source /Users/username/PycharmProjects/project-name/.venv/bin/activate
/Users/username/PycharmProjects/project-name/.venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install bpy

When running these commands, the terminal states, /MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Applications/PyCharm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory .
I changed the second command after determining that the PyCharm CE.app  was formatted incorrectly, changing it to PyCharm\ CE.app . After doing this, the command crashed, giving the same error as displayed in the PyCharm application:
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 2.82.1 Requires-Python >=3.7, <3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bpy

I've experimented with changing the version of the Python interpreter within PyCharm, installing older versions of Python, etc. Nothing fixes the issue. How can I get rid of this error and successfully install bpy?
It may help to know that other packages, like numpy, do install successfully.
Screenshot of Python interpreter settings

please add a screenshot of your Python interpreter configuration of PyCharm in your question.

I have now added that.

You need Python 3.7 to install that. The screenshot of your Python interpreter says you are using Python 3.13 (important part of the error is Requires-Python >=3.7, <3.8
